Landscape Issues while accessing via WEB-UI - OOPS ID: ['OOPS-81b9232a52f032cb7eb0b8c0ead79fe0']
Case Scenario : - Ubuntu Landscape integration is on pilot stage in my company. The objective is to support Ubuntu Clients. All configuration completed and accessible UI via browser.
Issue Faced - While Logout the Web-UI console, below OOPS Error message is displaying.
OOPS ID: ['OOPS-81b9232a52f032cb7eb0b8c0ead79fe0']

Moreover unable to reset the Administrator's password and receiving the same OOPS error.
How to resolve this?


